# Tapestry & Hibernate: Calling persist on EntityManager does not commit to database

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, tapestry

I'm trying to set up a web application using JBoss and Hibernate, but I can't get the SQL database running. When I'm persisting an object and immediately calling *contains()* returns true, but when I'm looking for this object in another method my database is just empty.

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="facePlace">
<non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/facePlace</non-jta-data-source>
<class>webtech2.faceplace.entities.Person</class>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

The relevant code:

```
@Inject
@Persistence
EntityManager em;

public boolean signUp(String name,
      String password,
      String repeatPassword,
      Date birthdate,
      String gender) {
if (!password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
  return false;
}

log.info("person data: " + name + " " + password + " " + repeatPassword + " " + birthdate.toString() + " " + gender);

String saltedPassword = hashText + password;
String hashedPassword = generateHash(saltedPassword);
Person xperson = new Person(name, hashedPassword, birthdate, gender);
em.persist(xperson);
return true;
}
```

I tried adding @CommitAfter here, resulted in the same error, as well as calling getTransaction.begin() and getTransaction.commit() what lead to

```
java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction!
```

My entity is:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

private String name;
private Date birthdate;
private long id;
private String password;
private String gender;
private Set<Person> friends;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
public long getId() {
  return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
  this.id = id;
}
```

When im seeing through the log I notice this warning that occurs when my second method tries to access the EntityManager:

```
HHH000436: Entity manager factory name (facePlace) is already registered.  If entity manager will be clustered or passivated, specify a unique value for property 'hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name'
```

Is this normal? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that's normal.

I never worked with JBoss though, so I can only point you to people who did:
[Transaction Handling in Tapestry5 with Jboss-5.1.0GA/JBoss-7.0.2](http://eubauer.de/kingsware/2011/05/25/transaction-handling-in-tapestry5-with-jboss-5-1-0ga/)